# Can we have two different application pool account in two Web front end servers

Tags: sharepoint-server, application-pool

We have two Web front servers and each has different application pool account for the central administration web site .Is this Correct? or

Do We need the common application pool account for same web site in both the WFE servers?

eg.

- WFE 1- Central Admin application pool account is : Account1
- WFE 2- Central Admin application pool account is : Account2

Please help

Satheesh S

Answer (score 1):

No this is not correct, Central Administration Application Pool run under the Farm Admin account (SP_Farm), which is unique account Farm wide not server specific.

Can I ask why you need different App Pool Account on each WFE?

When you create a Web Application it creates the App Pools on all WFE (except Central Administration) and same configuration across all servers.

> The server farm account, which is also referred to as the database access account, is used as the application pool identity for Central Administration and as the process account for the SharePoint Foundation 2013 Timer service.

[Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: The Scenario is in production servers we are facing some access denied error message when trying get the farm administrator users using SPAdministrationWebApplication. The issue is not happening in Dev,test or uat servers. we have noticed only the difference in app pool account for both WFE in production . Thanks Waqas for this quick help.

Comment: This answer and the link helps me understand why I need to run CA App Pool and Timer Service using SP_Farm. I spent a lot of time yesterday without trying to find information on it. Thanx Waqas - really helpful!